# What is the life cycle of web developing

Tags: lifecycle

I just wanted to get right picture of design cycle.  I have gathered list as follows,

- Requirement gathering
- Wireframe design
- Visual design (user interface)
- Mockup (prototype)
- Development

Do you have different view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However I have gathered the flow, it may be suggested or commented by community. And I wanted to enhance its technical names, I don’t know I much I’m success.

**Consultation**

- Content/ Functionality outline
- ite diagram
- Page description diagram

**Technical design**

- Wireframe
- Prototype
- Usability

**Visual**

- Concept
- Design Presentation/ UI Architecture
- Fine tuning

**Development**

- xHTML/ CSS/ JS
- Accessibility
- Compatibility

**Test**

- UI
- Content
- Accessibility
- Compatibility

Your ideas make this flow rich, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Analysis
2. Specification Building
3. Design and development
4. Content writing
5. Coding
6. Testing
7. Promotion
8. Maintenance and Updating